# Align secondary x-axis with main x-axis in Matplotlib/Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i got a little problem with Matplolib and Seaborn: basically, i want two different x-axis (with different values), and i want to align them. So, as you can see:
[image]

I want that the x-axis on top should be "constrained" according to the value of the main x-axis (in proportion)

Here's the code i use:

```
numeri = [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 5000000,10000000, 50000000, 100000000, 250000000]


def plot_time():
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    seaborn.set_context('talk')
    plt.title('CPU Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz')
    data_df = pd.melt(df_cores_shuffle, 'Num Cores')
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=data_df, x='value', y='Num Cores', hue='Num Cores', palette=[
        "#1f77b4", "#00FF00", "#00FFFF", "#00BFFF", "#8A2BE2"])
    ax.set(xlabel='Time (Seconds)', ylabel='# Cores')
    ax.set(yticks=num_cores)
    ax2 = ax.twiny()
    ax2.set_xticks(numeri)
    plt.show()
```

This is the `data_df`:

```
    Num Cores   variable     value
0           2       1000     0.003
1           3       1000     0.002 
2           4       1000     0.002
3           5       1000     0.002
4           6       1000     0.002
5           2      10000     0.025
6           3      10000     0.018
7           4      10000     0.014
8           5      10000     0.012
9           6      10000     0.011
10          2     100000     0.316
11          3     100000     0.177
12          4     100000     0.148
13          5     100000     0.144
14          6     100000     0.116
15          2    1000000     3.382
16          3    1000000     2.201
17          4    1000000     1.765
18          5    1000000     1.604
19          6    1000000     1.458
20          2    5000000    19.573
21          3    5000000    13.524
22          4    5000000    10.158
23          5    5000000     8.909
24          6    5000000     8.283
25          2   10000000    40.266
26          3   10000000    25.467
27          4   10000000    20.603
28          5   10000000    18.360
29          6   10000000    17.515
30          2   50000000   221.865
31          3   50000000   138.833
32          4   50000000   111.993
33          5   50000000    98.271
34          6   50000000    93.187
35          2  100000000   462.679
36          3  100000000   298.485
37          4  100000000   238.872
38          5  100000000   211.697
39          6  100000000   198.668
40          2  250000000  1281.431
41          3  250000000   819.359
42          4  250000000   671.026
43          5  250000000   606.328
44          6  250000000   567.414
```

EDIT: for JohanC

[image]

Comment: What I want to do is to plot the times required for cores. What I want is that I would also like to insert the analyzed numbers into this plot. I've edited the question so you can see what I mean

Comment: So, you want to align 0 with 0, and 2500 with something undetermined? Why are you only drawing 5 thin bars while you have 45 entries in the dataframe?

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest that you explain more clearly what you want to achieve.  How can people help if nobody understands what you are trying to do?  Why aren't you using the column 'variable' which seems to have a high impact on the 'Time'.

Comment: Use ax.secondary_axes as suggested above